# Golang type for Cassandra Decimal

Tags: go, cassandra

Sorry for asking this question but after being tired am writing it here.

I am not able to map any variable type of Golang to Cassandra's Decimal type, which is multi precision

I used interface {}, which works so long as I don't place value in the variable. The moment I do, it has issue

Answer (score 5):

You may use the infinite-precision decimal package and import this gopkg directly,

`import "gopkg.in/inf.v0"`

Let's say you have a particular model that reflects or binds to your Scylla/Cassandra table with a decimal data type,

```
type TradeModel struct {
    Balance *inf.Dec
}
```

To cast or convert your string to this decimal data type, you may use this function:

```
func ToDecimal(s string) *inf.Dec {
    d := new(inf.Dec)

    res, _ := d.SetString(s)
    return res
}
```

Take a look with these examples: https://github.com/go-inf/inf/blob/master/dec.go

NOTE: I did not explicitly write the second result from the return value of SetString for simplicity. That argument will return a boolean whether the conversion is success or not which is important (in my case this is already in direct helpers).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/master/helpers.go

As per this link I found that inf.Dec type of Golang maps to Cassandra's Decimal

```
var decimal inf.Dec
```

or

```
decimal := inf.NewDec(1, 0)
```